# Creating a Vim-Style Command Line Interface

Tags: user-interface, command-line, command-line-interface

I understand how to use stdin/stdout/stderr to interact with a user via the command line on a per-command basis (like git/maven/javac etc.)

However I would like to create a more Vim/Emacs-like interface. That is, when the program is run it clears the terminal, displays a full screen of characters, and deactivates echo. When finished the psuedo-window 'closes' and the terminal is returned to it's previous state, as if nothing happened.

I'd to know how to produce this window-like behaviour with a command line interface. I'm currently programming java for unix, but ideally I'd like a more general explanation.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what the [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) library (and its more popular implementation [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)) is for.  I recommend starting with [this ncurses tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).